# How to avoid a lot nested if...else statements, considering very specific conditions in C?

Tags: c, simulation

I'm simulating the interactions between two kind of particles in a square surface in C.

The steps of my simulations are the following:

1. We start with an empty surface and select at random a site of it.
2. We choose randomly between particle #1 and particle #2. To do so, we define a random number "r" so that if it's less than a given value "Y", particle #1 is chosen. Otherwise, we choose particle #2.
3. If particle #1 is chosen, we look up among the four nearest neighbors of the site. If among the nearest neighbors of such a site, any of them is occupied by particle #2, they react to form particle #3. Otherwise, particle #1 remains adsorbed.
4. If particle #2 is chosen, we look up among the four nearest neighbors of the site. If among the nearest neighbors of such a site, any of them is occupied by particle #1, they react to form particle #3. Otherwise, particle #2 remains adsorbed.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// define the dimensions of the grid
#define MAX_X 5
#define MAX_Y 5
// define the iterations
#define ITERATIONS (MAX_Y * MAX_X)
// define the partial pressure of particle #1
#define Y 0.55

FILE* data;

// define the states of a cell in grid`
typedef enum { S_EMPTY, P1_OCCUPIED, P2_OCCUPIED, S_NONE } gstate;

// help generate random coordinate of the grid
int gridrnd(int max) { return (rand() % max); }

// generates random coordinates of the grid
int generate_coords(int* j, int* i)
{
    if (!i || !j)
        return 1;

    *i = gridrnd(MAX_X);
    *j = gridrnd(MAX_Y);

    // printf("(%d,%d)\n\n", *j, *i);
    return 0;
}

// function to initialize the grid as empty
void grid_init(gstate grid[MAX_Y][MAX_X])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_Y; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_X; i++) {
            grid[j][i] = S_EMPTY;
        }
    }
}

// Function that locates the four nearest neighbors of the chosen site, considering
// periodic boundary conditions
int get_limited_coord(int coord, int coord_max)
{
    if (coord >= 0 && coord < coord_max) {
        return coord;
    } else if (coord >= coord_max) {
        return coord - coord_max;
    } else {
        return coord + coord_max;
    }
}

// Function that prints individually the "right" neighbor of the chosen site
gstate rightneighbor(int* x, int* y, gstate grid[MAX_X][MAX_Y], int* rx, int* ry)
{
    *ry = get_limited_coord(*y, MAX_Y);
    *rx = get_limited_coord(*x + 1, MAX_X);
    printf("right neighbor = (%d,%d)\n\n", *ry, *rx);
    return 0;
}

// Function that prints individually the "left" neighbor of the chosen site
gstate leftneighbor(int* x, int* y, gstate grid[MAX_X][MAX_Y], int* lx, int* ly)
{
    *ly = get_limited_coord(*y, MAX_Y);
    *lx = get_limited_coord(*x - 1, MAX_X);
    printf("left neighbor = (%d,%d)\n\n", *ly, *lx);
    return 0;
}

// Function that prints individually the "up" neighbor of the chosen site
gstate upneighbor(int* x, int* y, gstate grid[MAX_X][MAX_Y], int* ux, int* uy)
{
    ;
    *uy = get_limited_coord(*y - 1, MAX_Y);
    *ux = get_limited_coord(*x, MAX_X);
    printf("up neighbor = (%d,%d)\n\n", *uy, *ux);
    return 0;
}

// Function that prints individually the "down" neighbor of the chosen site
gstate downneighbor(int* x, int* y, gstate grid[MAX_X][MAX_Y], int* dx, int* dy)
{
    *dy = get_limited_coord(*y + 1, MAX_Y);
    *dx = get_limited_coord(*x, MAX_X);
    printf("down neighbor = (%d,%d)\n\n", *dy, *dx);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    data = fopen("results.txt", "w");
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    gstate grid[MAX_Y][MAX_X];
    int particle1 = 0, particle2 = 0,
        particle3 = 0; // counters for the number of particle1 and particle2
    int availcells =
        MAX_X * MAX_Y; // first we initialize with all the cells of the matrix available
    int fullcells = 0;
    int rounds = 0;
    int rx, ry, lx, ly, ux, uy, dx, dy;
    double N = 1.0 * sizeof(grid) /
               sizeof(grid[0][0]); // number of the total sites in the matrix
    double r = 0, r1 = 0, r2 = 0;

    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    // Initialize grid to be S_EMPTY
    grid_init(grid);

    while (rounds < N) {
        // LOCATE AN ENTRY OF THE MATRIX RANDOMLY
        generate_coords(&j, &i);

        // EVALUATE THE CHOOSEN SITE
        switch (grid[j][i]) {
        case S_EMPTY:
            // printf("IT'S S_EMPTY, LET'S FILL IT WITH A PARTICLE. FIRST LET'S GENERATE
            // TO DECIDE IFIT WILL BE TRAPPED\n\n");

            r = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
            printf("r = %lf\n", r);

            if (r <= Y) { // The particle #1 is chosen
                printf(
                    "r = %lf is less than Y = %lf. We choose the particle #1\n\n", r, Y);

                // let's find between the nearest neighbors of the particle #1 at random

                r1 = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
                printf("r1 = %lf\n", r1);

                rightneighbor(&i, &j, grid, &rx, &ry);
                leftneighbor(&i, &j, grid, &lx, &ly);
                upneighbor(&i, &j, grid, &ux, &uy);
                downneighbor(&i, &j, grid, &dx, &dy);

                if (r1 <= 0.25) {
                    // selects the right neighbor

                    if (grid[ry][rx] == P2_OCCUPIED) {
                        // if the right neighbor is occupied with the particle #2, they
                        // react and form the particle #3
                        grid[ry][rx] = S_EMPTY;
                        particle3++;
                        availcells++;
                        fullcells--;
                    } else {
                        // there is no site with particle #2, particle #1 reamins adsorbed
                        grid[j][i] = P1_OCCUPIED;
                        particle1++;
                        availcells--;
                        fullcells++;
                    }
                }

                else if (r1 <= 0.50) {
                    /// selects the left neighbor

                    if (grid[ly][lx] == P2_OCCUPIED) {
                        // if the left neighbor is occupied with the particle #2, they
                        // react and form the particle #3
                        grid[ly][lx] = S_EMPTY;
                        particle3++;
                        availcells++;
                        fullcells--;

                    } else {
                        // there is no site with particle #2, particle #1 reamins adsorbed
                        grid[j][i] = P1_OCCUPIED;
                        particle1++;
                        availcells--;
                        fullcells++;
                    }

                }

                else if (r1 <= 0.75) {
                    // selects the up neighbor

                    if (grid[uy][ux] == P2_OCCUPIED) {
                        // if the up neighbor is occupied with the particle #2, they react
                        // and form the particle #3
                        grid[uy][ux] = S_EMPTY;
                        particle3++;
                        availcells++;
                        fullcells--;

                    } else {
                        // there is no site with particle #2, particle #1 reamins adsorbed
                        grid[j][i] = P1_OCCUPIED;
                        particle1++;
                        availcells--;
                        fullcells++;
                    }

                }

                else if (r1 <= 1.00) {
                    // selects the down neighbor
                    if (grid[dy][dx] == P2_OCCUPIED) {
                        // if the down neighbor is occupied with the particle #2, they
                        // react and form the particle #3
                        grid[dy][dx] = S_EMPTY;
                        particle3++;
                        availcells++;
                        fullcells--;

                    } else {
                        // there is no site with particle #2, particle #1 reamins adsorbed
                        grid[j][i] = P1_OCCUPIED;
                        particle1++;
                        availcells--;
                        fullcells++;
                    }
                }
            }

            else { // The particle #2 is chosen
                printf("r = %lf is greater than Y = %lf. We choose the particle #2\n\n",
                       r,
                       Y);

                // let's find between the nearest neighbors of the particle #2 at random

                r2 = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
                printf("r2 = %lf\n", r2);

                rightneighbor(&i, &j, grid, &rx, &ry);
                leftneighbor(&i, &j, grid, &lx, &ly);
                upneighbor(&i, &j, grid, &ux, &uy);
                downneighbor(&i, &j, grid, &dx, &dy);

                if (r2 <= 0.25) {
                    // selects the right neighbor

                    if (grid[ry][rx] == P1_OCCUPIED) {
                        // if the right neighbor is occupied with the particle #1, they
                        // react and form the particle #3
                        grid[ry][rx] = S_EMPTY;
                        particle3++;
                        availcells++;
                        fullcells--;

                    } else {
                        // there is no site with particle #1, particle #2 reamins adsorbed
                        grid[j][i] = P2_OCCUPIED;
                        particle1++;
                        availcells--;
                        fullcells++;
                    }

                }

                else if (r2 <= 0.50) {
                    // selects the left neighbor

                    if (grid[ly][lx] == P1_OCCUPIED) {
                        // if the left neighbor is occupied with the particle #1, they
                        // react and form the particle #3

                        grid[ly][lx] = S_EMPTY;
                        particle3++;
                        availcells++;
                        fullcells--;

                    } else {
                        // there is no site with particle #1, particle #2 reamins adsorbed
                        grid[j][i] = P2_OCCUPIED;
                        particle1++;
                        availcells--;
                        fullcells++;
                    }

                }

                else if (r2 <= 0.75) {
                    // selects the up neighbor

                    if (grid[uy][ux] == P1_OCCUPIED) {
                        // if the up neighbor is occupied with the particle #1, they react
                        // and form the particle #3
                        grid[uy][ux] = S_EMPTY;
                        particle3++;
                        availcells++;
                        fullcells--;

                    } else {
                        // there is no site with particle #1, particle #2 reamins adsorbed
                        grid[j][i] = P2_OCCUPIED;
                        particle1++;
                        availcells--;
                        fullcells++;
                    }

                }

                else if (r2 <= 1.00) {
                    // selects the down neighbor

                    if (grid[dy][dx] == P1_OCCUPIED) {
                        // if the down neighbor is occupied with the particle #1, they
                        // react and form the particle #3
                        grid[dy][dx] = S_EMPTY;
                        particle3++;
                        availcells++;
                        fullcells--;

                    } else {
                        // there is no site with particle #1, particle #2 reamins adsorbed
                        grid[j][i] = P2_OCCUPIED;
                        particle1++;
                        availcells--;
                        fullcells++;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case P1_OCCUPIED:
            // printf("IT'S OCCUPIED WITH THE PARTICLE #1. PLEASE, GENERATE ANOTHER SITE
            // ON THE SURFACE\n\n");
            break;

        case P2_OCCUPIED:
            // printf("IT'S OCCUPIED WITH THE PARTICLE #2. PLEASE, GENERATE ANOTHER SITE
            // ON THE SURFACE\n\n");
            break;
        }
        rounds++;
    }
    printf("The process took %d rounds\n\n", rounds);
    printf("#particle1 = %d\n\n", particle1); // total of particle1 adsorbed
    printf("#particle2 = %d\n\n", particle2); // total of particle2 adsorbed
    printf("#particle3 = %d\n\n", particle3); // total of particle3 created
    printf("#availcells = %d\n\n", availcells);
    printf("#fullcells = %d\n\n", fullcells);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it is large and I'm not sure how to make it easier to maintain, debug, etc, mainly because I need to add additional particles and interactions in the future. Could you give me some suggestions to rewrite my code in a more condensed way?

Comment: Hint: your conditions are the same. let particle _x_ be chosen, we look up among the four nearest neighbors of the site. If any of them is occupied and not _x_, they react to form particle #3. Otherwise, particle _x_ remains adsorbed.

Comment: by the way, `rand()` is a pretty bad pseudorandom generator, and not even inherently thread-safe, so in a physics simulaiton, I'd maybe try to at least use a less *dangerous* random generator, or even better, a good one. [Here's](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/main/gnuradio-runtime/include/gnuradio/xoroshiro128p.h) a XOROSHIRO128+ implementation in C that is thread-safe, and also at least as fast (typically: faster) than `rand()`. Feel free to use it – I put it under LGPL for that express purpose

Comment: and: Whoever taught you that seeding a simulation with `time` was a good idea needs to be sternly talked to. In a physics simulation, you want the seed to be definite, so either hard-coded or possible to supply externally, so that you can run exactly the same simulation twice and get the same results. Seeding with `time` is double bad, because while it kills reproducibility, if you rely on two simulations being *different*, that doesn't work either, because on a modern computer, you could start thousands of simulations in the same second.

Comment: Your code does not appear to match your description.  You say that you model a reaction occurring if *any* of the nearest-neighbor sites contains the correct type of particule, but in fact, for each new particle you check *only one* of the nearest-neightbor sites.

Answer (score 2):

You can select a difference of x, y from an array based on result of `rand()`.

```
x, y - position of the particle

static const int d[4][2] = {
  { 1,  0}, // right
  {-1,  0}, // left
  { 0,  1}, // up
  { 0, -1}, // down
};

int r = rand() % 4;

int new_x = get_limited_coord(x + d[r][0], XMAX);
int new_y = get_limited_coord(y + d[r][1], YMAX);
```

Next, parametrize the "active" particle to exploit symmetry between P1 and P2.

```
r = rand() % 2;
gstate active = r ? P1_OCCUPIED : P2_OCCUPIED;
gstate other =  r ? P2_OCCUPIER : P1_OCCUPIED;
```

Finally, handle updating the state:

```
if (grid[new_y][new_x] == other) {
   grid[new_y][new_x] = S_EMPTY;
   particle3++;
   availcells++;
   fullcells--;
} else {
   grid[y][x] = active;
   if (active == P1_OCCUPIED)
     particle1++;
   else
     particle2++;
   availcells--;
   fullcells++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things, to add onto what @tstanisl said

First, I would encapsulate the grid itself in a structure:

```
typedef struct particle_grid {
    gstate grid[MAX_Y][MAX_X];
    
    int particle1_count;
    int particle2_count;
    int particle3_count;
    
    int availcells;
    int fullcells;
    
} particle_grid_s;
```

Encapsulating the state of the grid like this should make it more
maintainable in the future for a variety of reasons. I will leave
the modifications required to utilize this fully as an exercise.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with tstanisl's answer, but here's another
method that might make it easier to check if you have a particle1 + particle2,
and is extensible to other particle combinations:

```
#define P1_PRESENT_FLAG (1u << 0)
#define P2_PRESENT_FLAG (1u << 1)

//Call this with pointers to two cells, once they're selected
void react(particle_grid_s *grid, gstate *const new_particle, gstate *const neighbor){
    uint8_t particle_present = 0;
    
    if(*new_particle == P1_OCCUPIED || *neigbor == P1_OCCUPIED){
        particle_present |= P1_PRESENT_FLAG;
    }
    
    if(*new_particle == P2_OCCUPIED || *neigbor == P2_OCCUPIED){
        particle_present |= P2_PRESENT_FLAG;
    }
    
    if(particle_present == (P1_PRESENT_FLAG | P2_PRESENT_FLAG)){

        grid->particle3++;
        //we have a reaction. do rest of logic,
    }
    else{
        //No Reaction
    }
        
}
```

This could be extended for 6 more particle types or more if you change the type of particle_present. For example you could
check for particle1+particle3 by adding:

```
#define P3_PRESENT_FLAG (1u << 2)
//...below, adding to the logic of the react function
if(*new_particle == P3_OCCUPIED || *neigbor == P3_OCCUPIED){
    particle_present |= P3_PRESENT_FLAG;
}

//...
if(particle_present == (P1_PRESENT_FLAG | P2_PRESENT_FLAG)){
    //Do reaction logic since we have one of each
    
}
else if(particle_present == (P1_PRESENT_FLAG | P3_PRESENT_FLAG)){
    //We have p3+p1, make the necessary state modifications.
}
else{
    //No Reaction
}
```

There is not *always* a trick to making logic more easily readable/maintainable, but there *usually* is. It's mostly a matter of practice with this type of thinking.